# Looking for Electronic Documentary Research Software

Tags: exif, research

As the title may suggest, I'm not really sure what the type of software I'm looking for is called, or even if such thing exists for that matter!!

I'm looking for something that will aid me in my research.  Something I can drop images and video into and then add notes, draw pictures, annotate photos.  Hopefully something that will extract the exif data from the images too if possible so all I need is drop and drag and the basic info is logged all I need to do is add my annotations / notes etc....

The software should ideally run on Windows – although I'm open to Linux if this is the only alternative. With regard to web based, I'm not particularly fussy as long as it is usable and reliable. Preferably open source, however I'm not adversed to paying a reasonable price assuming it is proportional to the functionality provided :)

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: I may be way off, as I haven't really used it myself, but I have known people to use Microsoft OneNote to collect research.  Doubt it extracts EXIF, and it costs, but perhaps it's a rough option if sadly nothing else better exists.